# Problems with class hierarchy on Guice object

Tags: reflection, guice, objectify

I'm trying to use Guice to instantiate my Objectify DAOs. My hierarchy is the following:

```
public class EmpresaDao extends ObjectifyDao<Empresa> { ... }

public class ObjectifyDao<T> extends DAOBase { ... }
```

When I use "`new EmpresaDao()`", `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` gives me:

```
[INFO] superclass -> br.com.xxxxx.server.service.ObjectifyDao<br.com.xxxxx.domain.Empresa>
```

When I use "`injector.getInstance(EmpresaDao.class)`", `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` gives me:

```
[INFO] superclass -> class br.com.xxxx.server.service.EmpresaDao
```

Obviously, I want to let Guice instantiate my objects with DI.

Can someone explain why this is happen?

Is there any way (instantiating with Guice) to get the same superclass as with "new ()"?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Stuart McCulloch, who helped me [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-guice/4CJDdRs4zhk)

It's possible to disable AOP (using Guice whitout AOP) which gives me what I wanted (br.com.xxxxx.server.service.ObjectifyDao)  (not tested)

But I want to have AOP on my toolkit, so I've solved by getting the TypeArguments from the proxy classes generated by Guice:

```
        clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) TypeLiteral.get(getClass()).getSupertype(ObjectifyDao.class).getType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because Guice proxies  EmpresaDao, by dynamically creating bytecode and inheriting from  EmpresaDao.